# PIG:Twitter Sentiment Analysis

Tags: hadoop, twitter, apache-pig, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to implement the twitter sentiment analysis.I need to get all positive tweets and negative tweets and store them in particular text files.

**sample.json**

```
{"id": 252479809098223616, "created_at": "Wed Apr 12 08:23:20 +0000 2016", "text": "google is a good company", "user_id": 450990391}{"id": 252479809098223616, "created_at": "Wed Apr 12 08:23:20 +0000 2016", "text": "facebook is a bad company","user_id": 450990391}
```

**dictionary.text** having all the positive and negetive words list

```
weaksubj    1   bad     adj     n   negative
strongsubj  1   good    adj     n   positive
```

**Pig Script:-**

```
tweets = load 'new.json' using JsonLoader('id:chararray,text:chararray,user_id:chararray,created_at:chararray');

dictionary = load 'dictionary.text' AS (type:chararray,length:chararray,word:chararray,pos:chararray,stemmed:chararray,polarity:chararray);

words = foreach tweets generate FLATTEN( TOKENIZE(text) ) AS word,id,text,user_id,created_at;

sentiment = join words by word left outer, dictionary by word;

senti2 = foreach sentiment generate words::id as id,words::created_at as created_at,words::text as text,words::user_id as user_id,dictionary::polarity as polarity;

res = FILTER senti2 BY polarity MATCHES '.*possitive.*';
```

**describe res:-**

```
res: {id: chararray,created_at: chararray,text: chararray,user_id: chararray,polarity: chararray}
```

But when I dump res I dont see any output, but it executes fine without any errors.

What is the mistake that I am doing here.

Please suggest me.

Mohan.V

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 errors here

- 1 : line 2 - When you DUMP dictionary , you will see all the records
  in column 1 with rest of columns showing empty.

Solution : Specify an appropriate delimiter using PigStorage();

```
 dictionary = load 'dictionary.text' AS     (type:chararray,length:chararray,word:chararray,pos:chararray,stemmed:chararray,polarity:chararray);

DUMP dictionary;
(weaksubj    1   bad     adj     n   negative,,,,,)
(strongsubj  1   good    adj     n   positive,,,,,)
```

Second error : 
line 6 : Correct the spelling of positive ! use something like

```
res = FILTER senti2 BY UPPER(polarity) MATCHES '.*POSITIVE.*';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Sandesh.

Comment: I tried what u have suggested.

But still, its running success but no output.

Comment: I have edited the dictionary file by removing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I see spelling mistake in:

```
res = FILTER senti2 BY polarity MATCHES '.*possitive.*';
```

Isn't it `'.*positive.*'` ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my recommendations you should use custom UDF's for solving your problem . Now you can use elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar,json-simple-1.1.1.jar .
Also if you wanted to look at example for these then you can use these [Sentiment Analysis Tutorial](https://acadgild.com/blog/sentiment-analysis-on-tweets-using-afinn-dictionary/) . 
If you wanted code then you can refer these code and format your code according to tutorial and my code ,

```
REGISTER ‘/usr/local/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/ usr/local /elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/ usr/local /json-simple-1.1.1.jar’;
load_tweets = LOAD '/user/new.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS myMap;
extract_details = FOREACH load_tweets GENERATE myMap#'id' as id,myMap#'text' as text;
tokens = foreach extract_details generate id,text, FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(text)) As word;
dictionary = load '/user/dictionary.text' AS (type:chararray,length:chararray,word:chararray,pos:chararray,stemmed:chararray,polarity:chararray);
word_rating = join tokens by word left outer, dictionary by word using 'replicated’; describe word_rating;
rating = foreach word_rating generate tokens::id as id,tokens::text as text, dictionary::rating as rate;
word_group = group rating by (id,text);
avg_rate = foreach word_group generate group, AVG(rating.rate) as tweet_rating;
positive_tweets = filter avg_rate by tweet_rating>=0;
```